# How can I test methods in a large class with references to `self` using mock?

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking

Let's suppose I have a big class with methods that make many references to `self`. For example:

```
from unittest import mock
import json
import Gamma


class Alpha:
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = json.loads('file_A')
        self.b = json.loads('file_B')
        self.c = None
        self.d = None
        self.e = Gamma()

    def foo(self):
        json.dumps(self.d)

    def bar(self, dummy):
        self.c = dummy.x
        self.d = dummy.y
        self.foo()


class Beta:
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = json.loads('file_X')
        self.y = json.loads('file_Y')
```

Let's say I want to test the `bar` method in the above example utilizing mock. This is what I'm trying but I'm obviously missing something here:

```
@mock.patch('Beta', autospec=True)
@mock.patch('Alpha', autospec=True)
def test_bar(mock_alpha, mock_beta):
    # Set mock values so the Beta class gets instantiated properly
    mock_beta.x = 8
    mock_beta.y = 9

    # Call the bar method from mocked Alpha class
    mock_alpha.bar(mock_beta)

    # Test whether bar method updated the Alpha class as desired
    assert mock_alpha.c == 8
    assert mock_alpha.foo.called
```

These are the errors I get for the two asserts:

```
>               raise AttributeError("Mock object has no attribute %r" % name)
E               AttributeError: Mock object has no attribute 'c'


>       assert mock_alpha.foo.called
E       AssertionError: assert False
E        +  where False = <MagicMock name='Alpha.foo' spec='function' id='5324111568'>.called
E        +    where <MagicMock name='Alpha.foo' spec='function' id='5324111568'> = <MagicMock name='Alpha' spec='Alpha' id='5323992784'>.foo
```

How do I go about testing everything that `foo` does using mock?

PS: This is a stripped down example; it might make more sense to mock `json` object here in this particular example. However, in my real use case, the `Alpha` class is very complicated and would be a lot of work to mock all the endpoints. My question is confined to whether there's a way to mock instance of a class the way I'm attempting (unsuccessfully) to do in the example.

Comment: `__init__` should take arguments to set most of those attributes; then you don't need to mock *anything*; you just create an appropriate instance to test.

Comment: (You can still wrap an instance of `Alpha` to test if its `foo` method is called, but it would be better if you could look for the desired *result* of `foo` being called, as maybe the implementation will change at some point.)

Answer (score 1):

I will patch `json.loads()` method instead of patching `Beta` class. Besides, I patched `.foo()` method of `Alpha` class.

E.g.

`main.py`:

```py
import json


class Alpha:
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = json.loads('file_A')
        self.b = json.loads('file_B')
        self.c = None
        self.d = None

    def foo(self):
        json.dumps(self.d)

    def bar(self, dummy):
        self.c = dummy.x
        self.d = dummy.y
        self.foo()


class Beta:
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = json.loads('file_X')
        self.y = json.loads('file_Y')
```

`test_main.py`:

```py
from unittest import mock
import unittest
from main import Alpha, Beta


class TestAlpha(unittest.TestCase):
    @mock.patch('main.json.loads')
    @mock.patch('main.Alpha.foo')
    def test_bar(self, mocked_foo, mocked_json_loads):
        def json_loads_side_effect(s):
            if s == 'file_X':
                return 'a'
            if s == 'file_Y':
                return 'b'

        mocked_json_loads.side_effect = json_loads_side_effect
        alpha = Alpha()
        beta = Beta()
        alpha.bar(beta)
        self.assertEqual(alpha.c, 'a')
        self.assertEqual(alpha.d, 'b')
        mocked_foo.assert_called_once()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

test result:

```
.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.001s

OK
Name                                      Stmts   Miss  Cover   Missing
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
src/stackoverflow/68402729/main.py           17      1    94%   12
src/stackoverflow/68402729/test_main.py      21      0   100%
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
TOTAL                                        38      1    97%
```

Comment: You're right, for this example that would make more sense. I should have been more clear on that. This example is just a proof of concept, in my class actual class, there are too many end-points to mock. I was wondering if there's a way to implement mock by mocking the class instance instead?

Comment: @slideshop2 the issue with the solution you posted for my use-case is that `alpha = Alpha()` wouldn't have enough context to execute any methods properly. Adding/mocking all the required contexts would be a lot of work.

Answer (score 0):

After researching this for a while and considering @slideshowp2 's answer to this question. I have found a solution to be most close to what I was looking for. It seems like my initial idea of mocking entire class `Alpha` is unfeasible, instead I can mock any endpoints of `Alpha` but will need to have `Alpha` instantiated one way or another.

Here's my final solution that works.

```
@pytest.fixture
def set_up_alpha():
    """
    Use this fixture to set-up an instance of Alpha object
    Mock any endpoints as necessary
    """
    with mock.patch.object(json, 'loads') as mock_json_loads:
        mock_json_loads.side_effect = lambda x: "test_string"
        a = Alpha()

        yield a


@mock.patch.object(Alpha, 'foo', autospec=True)
def test_bar(mock_foo, set_up_alpha):
    """
    GIVEN an Alpha object
        AND a mocked Beta object
    WHEN the bar method is invoked
    THEN corresponding instances of Alpha object are updated
        AND method foo is called
        AND the method does not return anything
    """

    # Use a mocked object for Beta instance
    class MockBeta:
        x = "test_x"
        y = "test_y"

    # Instantiate an Alpha object
    a = set_up_alpha

    output = a.bar(MockBeta)

    # Test whether bar method updated the Alpha class as desired
    assert a.c == "test_x"
    assert a.d == "test_y"
    assert mock_foo.called
    assert output is None
```